# Reading Dynamic Column Families from Cassandra with Kettle

Tags: cassandra, kettle

I have to migrate data from one cluster to another doing some transformations on the data. I am trying to use Kettle to do that folowing this tutorial:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Cassandra+Input

But I am trying to read from a dynamic column family that was created throught the cli (in previous versions of Cassandra) with this:

create column family IndividualMorphsIndividuals with read_repair_chance=0 and gc_grace=0;

I create the cassandra input step like this:

[image]

When I click on show schema appears this information:

Column family: IndividualMorphsIndividuals
    Key validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
    Column comparator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
    Default column validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
    Read repair chance: 0.0
    GC grace: 0
    Min compaction threshold: 4
    Max compaction threshold: 32
    Replicate on write: true

```
Column metadata:
```

But when I tried to preview the step, I get this error:

```
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - Getting meta data for column family IndividualMorphsIndividuals
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - Executing query SELECT * FROM IndividualMorphsIndividuals;  ...
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Cant find a deserializer for type "{0}"
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.cassandra.CassandraColumnMetaData.getColumnValue(CassandraColumnMetaData.java:965)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.cassandra.CassandraColumnMetaData.getColumnName(CassandraColumnMetaData.java:878)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputData.cassandraRowToKettle(CassandraInputData.java:567)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInput.processRow(CassandraInput.java:271)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Cassandra Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2013/11/06 08:17:22 - Transformation 1 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2013/11/06 08:17:23 - Transformation 1 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
```

Does anyone know how to operate with this kind of column families with Kettle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with this problem but didn't find any solution so i changed instead of CLI i used cql (cassandra query language) and as i was using pdi 4.4 so we have to add 1 pluggin for CQL and then you can easily connect cassandra to kettle.

Follow the link for connecting cassandra through CQL

[Connecting Cassandra through CQL](http://devasive.blogspot.in/2012/10/cql-terminal-for-cassandra-on-windows.html)

Comment: if you people want to use this then let me know i will share the appropriate links for the same..

Comment: If you have the appropiate links why you dont share then? @working_hard

Comment: I have edited my answer.. Just follow it, it you got struck then let me know. Link will help you for sure.